# Using @PostConstruct in a test class causes it to be called more than once

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit4, spring-test

I am writing integration tests to test my endpoints and need to setup a User in the database right after construct so the Spring Security Test annotation `@WithUserDetails` has a user to collect from the database.

My class setup is like this:

```
@RunWith(value = SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WithUserDetails(value = "email@address.com")
public abstract class IntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private Service aService;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() throws UserCreationException {
        // Setup and save user data to the db using autowired service "aService"

        RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc(mockMvc);
    }

    @Test
    public void testA() {
        // Some test
    }

    @Test
    public void testB() {
        // Some test
    }

    @Test
    public void testC() {
        // Some test
    }

}
```

However the `@PostConstruct` method is called for **every** annotated `@Test`, even though we are not instantiating the main class again.

Because we use Spring Security Test (`@WithUserDetails`) we need the user persisted to the database BEFORE we can use the JUnit annotation `@Before`. We cannot use `@BeforeClass` either because we rely on the `@Autowired` service: `aService`.

A solution I found would be to use a variable to determine if we have already setup the data (see below) but this feels dirty and that there would be a better way.

```
@PostConstruct
private void postConstruct() throws UserCreationException {
    if (!setupData) {
        // Setup and save user data to the db using autowired service "aService"

        RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc(mockMvc);
        setupData = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR : Keep your way for the moment. If later the boolean flag is repeated in multiple test classes create your own `TestExecutionListener`.

In JUnit, the test class constructor is invoked at each test method executed.
So it makes sense that `@PostConstruct` be invoked for each test method.
According to JUnit and Spring functioning, your workaround is not bad. Specifically because you do it in the base test class.

As less dirty way, you could annotate your test class with `@TestExecutionListeners` and provide a custom `TestExecutionListener` but it seem overkill here as you use it once.
In a context where you don't have/want the base class and you want to add your boolean flag in multiple classes, using a custom `TestExecutionListener` can make sense.
Here is an example.

Custom TestExecutionListener :

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestExecutionListener;

public  class MyMockUserTestExecutionListener extends AbstractTestExecutionListener{

    @Override
    public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        MyService myService = testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(MyService.class);
        // ... do my init
    }
}
```

Test class updated :

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WithUserDetails(value = "email@address.com")
@TestExecutionListeners(mergeMode = MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS, 
                        value=MyMockUserTestExecutionListener.class) 
public abstract class IntegrationTests {
 ...
}
```

Note that  `MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS` matters if you want to merge `TestExecutionListener`s coming from the Spring Boot test class with `TestExecutionListener`s defined in the `@TestExecutionListeners` of the current class.
The default value is `MergeMode.REPLACE_DEFAULTS`.